# Custom YouTube Player - Can I get a player like this to embed on my site?

Tags: html, iframe

Would like an embeddable player which also shows thumbnails or previews of other videos in a playlist.  What I have ON Youtube itself is perfect.  Is this doable?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5ezOPDo6rE&list=PL972B9B9D1E7341C4

Comment: do you want the style like the page before or just the functionality off embedding videos with playlists

Comment: Thank you for response - I am looking to embed a player referencing a playlist that also shows (thumbnails) additional videos within that playlist while a video is playing...That way a viewer can browse other clips in the playlist while watching one.  I would like to have the player function as close as possible to what is shown in the link.

Comment: Ahh ok because you can do this with the default embed player by clicking playlist on the bottom corner but it doesn't open automatically.

Comment: correct.   That is what I am trying to make happen. This task used to be very simple, but I am not able to track down a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey try setting the showinfo variable below is a snippet from youtube dev pages [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playlist)

> If the player is loading a playlist, and you explicitly set the
>   parameter value to 1, then, upon loading, the player will also display
>   thumbnail images for the videos in the playlist. Note that this
>   functionality is only supported for the AS3 player since that is the
>   only player that can load a playlist.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/cNwHc/

```
 <iframe width="1280" height="720" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/T5ezOPDo6rE?list=PL972B9B9D1E7341C4&showinfo=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: that helps greatly for now!  Thank you!!   - If you know of a way to put the thumbnails "permanently" on the right hand side, that would be helpful as well.